# Best way to implement simple sorting / searching in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, sorting, searchlogic

What's the best way to implement an interface that looks like this in rails?

[image: interface example]

Currently I'm using Searchlogic, and it's a tad painful. Problems include:

- Making sure certain operations remain orthogonal -- for example, if you select "Short Posts" and then search, your search results should be restricted to short posts.
- Making sure the correct link gets the "selected" class. Right now the links are `<a>`'s, so maintaining this state client-side is tricky. I'm hacking it by having the AJAX response to, say, sorting return a new sort links section with the correct link "selected". Using radio buttons instead of `<a>` tags would make it easier to maintain state client-side -- maybe I should do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recently solved a similar problem using named_scopes and some ruby metaprogramming that I rolled up into a plugin called [find_by_filter](http://github.com/tobyhede/acts_as_filter/tree/master).

> **find_by_filter** accepts a hash of scope
>   names and values, and chains them into
>   parametised scope calls. If the model has a named_scope that matches the provided name, this is called.If no named_scope is found, an anonymous scope is created.

Comment: Cool! Does find_by_filter deal with SQL injection etc?

Comment: Parameters are bound in your named scopes - so if you handle that correctly you should be fine. The internals are quite simple - feel free to just rip off the idea :P.
Scopes can be chained to form complex queries - that's really the core of the approach.

I also validate against anticipated filter options (using something like "if accepted.include?(params[:filter])" where accepted is an array of accepted strings.